# Mutating text using a function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use a function to mutate a column with dplyr.

Data to replicate:

```
dates<-tbl_df(data.frame(Dates=c(as.Date("2002-12-31"),as.Date("2003-01-31"))))
```

Function:

```
getfilename <- function(date) str_c("EQS_",format(date, format="%Y%m%d"),".csv")
```

dplyr code:

```
expected<-dates %>%   rowwise() %>%  mutate(filenames=getfilename(Dates))
```

Expected output: A column appended, containing:

```
"EQS_20021231.csv"
"EQS_20030231.csv"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. The function for string concatentation is `paste0`. Also, you don't need the `rowwise` call. The `mutate` function always operates rowwise.

```
dates <- tbl_df(data.frame(Dates=c(as.Date("2002-12-31"),as.Date("2003-01-31"))))
getfilename <- function(date) paste0("EQS_",format(date, format="%Y%m%d"),".csv")
expected <- dates %>% mutate(filenames=getfilename(Dates))
```

Comment: Thank you drhagen, much appreciated. I am perplexed though, why str_c() didn't work? str_c() is a wrap around paste, and paste0 is simply paste with sep="". Any ideas?

Comment: `str_c` is not a function in base R. It is a function in the `stringr` package.

Comment: Huh, if I load `str_c` from `stringr`, it still doesn't work. I'm not exactly sure why from reading the docs, but then again, I've never used that function, so I'm not sure what it is for.

Comment: Issue resolved [here](https://github.com/hadley/stringr/issues/102), an update of the stringi package is required.